# How to access elements rendered in another React component?

Tags: reactjs

I have an app that looks roughly like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    var ComponentTwo = this.props.getComponentTwo();
    return (
     <div>
       <ComponentOne />
       {ComponentTwo ? <ComponentTwo /> : []}
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The ComponentTwo is not always the same component class and sometimes it needs to interact with ComponentOne - namely - select certain elements from it and attach some listeners to them.

I want this functionality to come with ComponentTwo because it's only needed when ComponentTwo is loaded and it comes with a lot of code.

What are the best practice to allow one component to dynamically extend another sibling component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the correct way to implement such a scenario in React is to change state of the App component after some action in ComponentTwo and then pass state changes to ComponentOne:

```
  onComponentTwoAction: function(someValueFromAction) {
    this.setState({
        componentOneProp: someValueFromAction
    });
  }, 
  render: function(){
    var ComponentTwo = this.props.getComponentTwo();
    return (
     <div>
       <ComponentOne componentOneProp={this.state.componentOneProp}/>
       {ComponentTwo ? <ComponentTwo onAction={this.onComponentTwoAction}/> : []}
     </div>
    );
  }
```